# Multipear Connectivity framework device connection Issue

Tags: ios, iphone

I am connecting two devices with multipeer connectivity but sometime it is connected with other device and sometimes not connected. If any one have idea. Please help me. I am in trouble.

Comment: hi I am also facing this problem.. do you get solution?

Answer (score 1):

Look at this [apple's doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/iOS_Simulator_Guide.pdf)

or also you can use for your help go to below [url](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/RunYourApp/RunYourApp.html).